# Case-sensitive string comparison in SQL (MariaDB, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, case-sensitive, libmysql

I have read many questions and answers on StackOverflow (posted years ago) concerning this issue, but none that I found have worked using a **10.3.22-MariaDB** server and **libmysql - 5.6.43** as database client.

I am trying to do the following:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'column' = 'data' LIMIT 1`
The command above, however, will select the row both if the value of `column` is `DaTa` or `data` and I am endeavouring to go for the latter only.

Answers to similar questions from 2011 (MySQL) suggest:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE BINARY 'column' = 'data'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'column' = BINARY 'data'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'column' LIKE BINARY 'data'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'column' LIKE 'data' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

None of the commands above respected the case of the letters. Moreover, the last one did not even run due to

> 1. Unrecognized keyword. (near "COLLATE" at position 45)
> 2. Unexpected token. (near "latin1_general_cs" at position 53)

What is the solution to this problem in 2020? What am I doing wrong or what is wrong with my server?
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
WHERE BINARY column = 'data'
```

However, it will not work if you put `column` in single quotes.  That would be a string as opposed to a column reference.

Answer (score 1):

This works without the single quotes around cloumn

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `column` LIKE 'data' COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

As you asked the collation has to fir to the character set, so if you have like  me utf8mb5, you write:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `column` LIKE _latin1 'data'   COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: I have the same two errors when using this. Perhaps it is just my server configuration that does not support it.

Comment: which version do you have mariadb 10.3 and 10.4 works just fine mysql also in version 8 which i tested,  so be more accurate

Comment: there is also the problem that your selected collation don't work with utf8mb4, so maybe this could also be aproblem, but you where very sparse with information

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I am using 10.3.22-MariaDB server and libmysql - 5.6.43 as a database client

Comment: I added how you would do it with a utf8mb4 database/table/column, which doesn't know latin_general_ci, you have always to check for it. this works under evry database in mysql/mariadb. If you still get errors you have to provide a fiddle example so that i can check